# My SelectedItem that is bonded to an attribute does not get the right data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I have this class for my TabControl where i define all my tabs.

```
public class TabViewModel
{
    public static int selectedPos { get; set; }
    public static ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
    public TabViewModel(DocumentModel document)
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
    }
    public  class TabItem
    {
        public ICommand CloseCommand { get; }
        public TabItem()
        {
            CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(Close);

        }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public void Close()
        {
            //DocumentModel document = new DocumentModel();
            //document.FilePath = Tabs[selectedPos].Path;
            //document.Text = Tabs[selectedPos].Content;
            //File.WriteAllText(document.FilePath, Tabs[selectedPos].Content);

            Tabs.RemoveAt(selectedPos);
        }
    }
```

This is the xaml file where i have th TabControl

```
    <TabControl  x:Name="TabControl" DataContext="{Binding TabView}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding selectedPos,
        Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate  >
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox
                Text="{Binding Content}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
            
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

My problem is witt the selectedPos of Tabs.Each time selectedPos stays to 0 even if I go to another tab that is in a different position.I just need selectedPos to get the correct position.

Comment: That is because you are not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `TabViewModel` so the control has no way of knowing that `selectedPos` changed.   Implement that interface in `TabViewModel`.  Change the `selectedPos` property to not be static.  When the value changes, raise the `PropertyChanged` event.  This is fundamental to MVVM.

Comment: When i change it to don t be static when i try to access the selectePos like this: Document.FilePath = TabViewModel.Tabs[TabViewModel.selectedPos].Path; it says that an object reference is requiered for the non-static field,method,or property 'TabViewModel.selectedPos'

Comment: You need to create an instance of `TabViewModel`.  Because there must be an object for`TabControl ` to bind to.  Then you need to set that that instance (of `TabViewModel`) to be the `DataContext` of `TabControl`.  Look, I don't want to sound harsh but the things I'm speaking of here are what you would find in an introductory text to WPF.  So that's what you need.  Go find a tutorial or a text book and read it.    It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedPos` should be a (non-static) instance property:

```
public int selectedPos { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, i.e. if it is static, you should bind to it like this:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=(local:TabViewModel.selectedPos)}"
```

Also note that you should use the `SelectedIndex` property of the `TabControl` to bind to an `int` source property.

`SelectedItem` refers to the currently selected `TabItem` object.